# how to remove HTML tag inside the XML tag after parsing RSS?

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

Hi every one I have a parsing RSS question.

Current, I am able to parse the RSS XML on the news web, and display it in the UITableViewCell. I parse the description tag which is:

```
<description><![CDATA[ <a href="http://vnexpress.net/gl/xa-hoi/2012/05/thuy-dien-song-tranh-de-bi-lo-sut-dat-1/"><img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/66/e0/sat-lo-dat-Song-Tranh-2.jpg"></a>this is new<BR />></description>
```

The problem now that I how can I just get out the text inside this tag? Currently it display everything inside the description tag, which is:

```
<![CDATA[ <a href="http://vnexpress.net/gl/xa-hoi/2012/05/thuy-dien-song-tranh-de-bi-lo-sut-dat-1/"><img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/66/e0/sat-lo-dat-Song-Tranh-2.jpg"></a>this is new<BR />>
```

I just want the plain text to be displayed:

```
this is new
```

And I also wanna get the image in this description tag so I can display it:

```
<img src="http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/66/e0/sat-lo-dat-Song-Tranh-2.jpg">
```

. Please tell me how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this before. so I will paste the code I used here.

```
- (NSString *)removeHTMLTags:(NSString *)str
{   
NSMutableString *temp_str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:str];
NSRange openTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@"<"];
NSRange closeTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@">"];

while (openTag.length > 0) {
    NSRange range;
    range.location = openTag.location;
    range.length = (closeTag.location - openTag.location) + 1;
    [temp_str setString:[temp_str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""]];

    openTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@"<"];
    closeTag = [temp_str rangeOfString:@">"];
}

[temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Auml;" withString:@"Ä" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
[temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&Aring;" withString:@"Å" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
[temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"&AElig;" withString:@"Æ" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];


while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@"  "].location != NSNotFound) {
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
}

while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ."].location != NSNotFound) {
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ." withString:@"." options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
}

while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ,"].location != NSNotFound) {
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ," withString:@"," options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
}

while ([temp_str rangeOfString:@" ;"].location != NSNotFound) {
    [temp_str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" ;" withString:@";" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp_str length])];
}


return temp_str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, btw, do u know how to get an image from HTML tag like this : <img src=\"http://vnexpress.net/Files/Subject/3b/bd/66/e0/sat-lo-dat-Song-Tranh-2.jpg\">

Answer (score -1):

For iOS 7+ you can use `NSAttributedString` as following:

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

for lower than iOS 7 use this code which removes everything between < and >

```
(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
}
```